# Magento XML RPC API - Coupons

Tags: api

I am trying to pull a sales order coupon code using the XML-RPC API:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html

I don't see this field available. Can I pull order coupon codes using XML-RPC?

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible. Looking at http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/imagine2012-barcamp-magento-api.pdf(page 10) this feature is marked as future plan. Also looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190261/magento-api-cart-coupon-add-does-not-work confirms that it is not possible (for now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Magento wont pull the "Coupon code" detail to the Order List using API. Instead the rule id will be available on the field **applied_rule_ids**. All the native fields list are available [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new module and add a *wsdl.xml* file in etc folder (or add inside another module's wsdl.xml file) with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <complexType name="salesOrderEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="coupon_code" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

---

Note: if you are using a php script to consume the api, don't forget to add the following line before making the soap call (to avoid wsdl php cache):

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
```